# Calling JS function inside a WordPress do_action

Tags: wordpress

I have this JS function named as "myjsfunction()".

```
function myjsfunction() {

jQuery('#html_admin_show').hide();
jQuery('#html_admin_edit').show();

}
```

How is it possible to call this JS function inside a Wordpress do_action hook?

I'm preferring to add it as third parameter because I'm already using the second parameter, so something like:

```
do_action('myhelp', 'mysecondfunction', 'myjsfunction');
```

But it is not showing the element #html_admin_edit when the page runs. Any ideas how to call this function?

Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have my answers here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/79969/adding-js-function-as-third-parameter-in-do-action/79970#79970

The trick is to enclose the Javascript function within PHP and call them one by one using do_action. Hope this helps.